Why does io.ktor.websocket.WebSocketSession.send throw a CancellationException when tcp connection closed?
If the session is closed by tcp connection or peer, a CancellationException is thrown, which has a very significant impact on the flow of the coroutine and can be very dangerous.
What I expect is an ChannelClosedException or similar exception thrown.
As I understand it, CancellationException is generally thrown when the user has explicit intent:

scope.cancel, job.cancel
withTimeout
deferred.await
parent-child coroutine cancellation propagation

Now, a normal send function throws it, so aren't there many more such functions that might throw CancellationException? This would make the program's exception checking very complicated. It is more likely that the problem is not recognized.
    @Test
    fun testChannelSendCatchCancellationException(): Unit = runBlocking {
        val server = MockWebServer()
        server.start()
        val serverUrl = server.url("/").toString().replaceFirst("http", "ws")
        println(serverUrl)

        val response = MockResponse().withWebSocketUpgrade(object : WebSocketListener() {
            override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
                val request = server.takeRequest()
                println(request)
                webSocket.close(3000, "goodbye")
            }
        })
        server.enqueue(response)

        val session = HttpClient { install(WebSockets) }.webSocketSession(serverUrl)
        launch {
            try {
                delay(500L)
                try {
                    session.send(Frame.Text("Hello, world"))
                    // Some other codes need to call when success
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    // MY QUESTION: how to differentiate between a user's cancellation and a send failure?
                    // For withTimeout, it throws TimeoutCancellationException, differed from CancellationException
                    println("session tx caught: $e")
                    // Some other codes need to call when failed
                }
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                println("tx coroutine caught cancellation: $e")
                throw e
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("tx coroutine caught exception: $e")
                // it prints: tx coroutine caught: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Channel was cancelled
            }
        }
        delay(200L)
        server.close()
        delay(200L)
    }

If send throws a different exception than CancellationException, it is easier to handle, otherwise the code is very redundant. Because I need to distinguish whether it's a user canceling, or a normal send failure.

Could you share some code that presents the problem? What does it mean that: "Even if a ClosedChannelException or similar is thrown, a CancellationException is thrown"? It is not possible two exceptions are thrown at the same time.

When a coroutine fails with an error other parts of your coroutine hierarchy may be cancelled as well, depending on your setup. These parts may receive a CancellationException as part of the cancellation mechanism of coroutines. Please provide a [mre] and better describe what your issue is with the behavior it exhibits.

@broot Sorry for my confused description. Now I have correct it. Thank you very much

@tyg I mean, if I fail to send it, I actually have a lot of program logic to deal with it; but I get a CancellationException, and I think it's usually the user or the lifecycle that cancels it. Those are two completely different intents that I'm mixing up to deal with.

I agree, if send throws CancellationException because socket was closed, then this is definitely unexpected. If this is not somehow related to your specific setup (maybe something else is going on with these mocks, etc.), then I consider this to be a bug in Ktor client.

@broot thanks. This issue is found in my real project. I just use a unit test mock server to reproduce it for sharing.

I agree this is a bug, however, I don't think this is a bug in the Ktor client itself. Instead, I believe it may be related to an issue within the Channel in the Coroutine library.

I interpret the question to be about how you should handle cases where a CancellationException is thrown that is not part of the coroutine framework. Which is quite possible, since on the JVM a kotlin.coroutines.cancellation.CancellationException is just a typealias of java.util.concurrent.CancellationException. And that is likely used by various other frameworks unrelated to coroutines.
Regarding your specific case please skip to the last part.
The general advice would be to isolate the error handling of Java code's CancellationException from that related to coroutines. That is possible because coroutines in Kotlin are cooperative: If you do not want your coroutine to be cancelled nothing can stop you from ignoring a cancellation request.
That means you have to actively check for a cancellation request, and only if you want to honor the cancellation request you should throw a CancellationException. delay, for example, does that. So when you call other suspend functions they may throw a CancellationException indicating that they want to cooperate and cancel the execution of the current coroutine. That is an exception that - in the spirit of cooperation - you should rethrow. It's necessary for the coroutine framework to function properly
When, on the other hand, a Java function (that doesn't suspend) throws a CancellationException that exception has another meaning. You do not need to rethrow it since it isn't meant to control the flow of coroutines. You might not even be in a coroutine, since Java functions cannot enforce that by declaring themselves as suspending. That means you can safely catch CancellationExceptions originating from non-suspending Java code. You can even do that while in a coroutine without running risk catching a coroutine-related CancellationException since the latter can only be thrown from suspending functions, which your non-suspending Java function is not.

In your specific case where Ktor's WebSocketSession::send throws a CancellationException the situation is a little bit different. That function is a suspending function and you do not know the reason for the exception. It may be an internal call to ensureActive() to cooperate with coroutine cancellation, or it may be caused by a closed websocket connection or by something entirely different.
The point is, you do not know. Since the function is explictily marked as suspending, your only safe route to go is to interpret the exception as a means to control the coroutine. That means you shouldn't catch it (or at least rethrow it), while not being sure what the cause was. The only thing you know is that you couldn't send the frame and the current coroutine should be stopped.
You may disagree with the decision of the Ktor team to throw a CancellationException when the connection was closed, but there are also arguments for it. This is what the documentation has to say about it:

May throw an exception if the outgoing channel is already closed, so it is impossible to transfer any message. Frames that were sent after close frame could be silently ignored.

If you encapsulate the websocket call in a coroutine it shouldn't matter much that the coroutine is getting cancelled, the important part is to know that the message couldn't be sent. And when the websocket connecion is still open you can simply retry, lauching a new coroutine.

thank you very much. But I can not accept your answer. I still think that a CancellationException has to be something that the user can throw when they intend to throw it, rather than a non-cancel intent like send, otherwise the program would be very, very complex to structure in order to differentiate between the two intents.
